# Deploying - MySQL with Entity Frame Work

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, web-config

I have an MVC4 app which is ready to be deployed. The app is database first entity framework with **MySQL** not MSSQL. As far as dubugging goes, I have no errors with the connection string below but when I go to deploy the app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk it brings me to the login screen but when i go to login, it throws an error:

```
 Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
```

I'm not sure what the correct way to have a web.config configured for MySQL Deployments assuming that the web config is the problem to begin with. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Web.Config:

```
     <configuration>
 <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyFinDevEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyFinAdminModel.csdl|res://*/MyFinAdminModel.ssdl|res://*/MyFinAdminModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;user id=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;server=xxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;database=xxxxDev&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  />  <!-- providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"-->
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is Connector/Net installed on the destination server?

Comment: @Brice I'm deploying to Elastic Beanstalk EC2 Server for Amazon, so I would have to install this connector on the EC2 Instance? How do I go about doing this? Thanks for input

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Amazon technologies, but essentially you have two options. 1) Deploy a copy of MySql.Data.dll (and MySql.Data.Entities.dll) to the bin directory (known as bin-deploying), or 2) Download and install [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) on the server that executes the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are bin-deploying/xcopying MySQL's Connector/Net provider, you may need to add the following fragment to your web.config

```xml
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         description="Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```